# Disable Javascript in Playwright

Tags: playwright

Is it possible to define a browser with Javascript disabled to simulate how a crawler would view a page? There should be an option that can be passed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass `javaScriptEnabled` in the BrowserContext options:

```
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext({
    javaScriptEnabled: false
  });
  const page = await context.newPage();
  // ...
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Hi, In the case of python, you can use:                                                                                                   page = browser.new_page(user_agent="<your user_agent>", java_script_enabled=False)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of [@playwright/test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@playwright/test) (where you don't define `browser.newContext` yourself) you can set `javaScriptEnabled` in [`testOptions`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-java-script-enabled).

(1) In the `playwright.config.js` file:

```js
const config = {
  use: {
    headless: false,
    javaScriptEnabled: false
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

(2) or with `test.use`:

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
test.use({ javaScriptEnabled: false });

test('website without JavaScript', async ({ page }) => {
  // ...
});
```